# Could not load file or assembly, system could not find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am getting this error:
Could not load file or assembly, system could not find the file specified.

Images:

http://s30.postimg.org/4x936f6ch/error2.png

http://s17.postimg.org/41ta9aaj3/errro3.png

I have a solution built in .NET 4.0
In it I have projects that act as plugins. They use dlls and the issue is that one of the solutions projects dlls is being called, and that references the dll that is causing the issue. 
I get no error when rebuilding etc just when the program gets to the part where it uses the dll that references this one.

I have also made sure that in the projects bin folder that it has the dll that it is complaining about.

I have opened the dll in reflector and I don't think it has any issues.
COuld someone point me to the next step to try with fixing this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of tips - hard to know if they'll help you:

> 1. Open the csproj file(s) in a text editor and see where the dlls are being referenced (GAC possibly)
> 2. If it's a signed assembly, make sure you've got a signed copy (if you've built an Open Source project yourself the signing will be lost)
> 3. Look at the references in Visual Studio - do you have Copy Local set to True and Specific Version set to False?
> 4. Look at you're App.config or Web.config - is there a binding redirect that failing to load
> 5. I remember reading a post about assemblies not being able to be unloaded - probably not an issue on this one but I think the trick was
>      to load the DLL in a separate AppDomain to keep it isolated - loadable
>      and unloadable.