# NET 5 DLL is present but does not load

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-5

This question is about why an assembly cannot find a library that resides in the same folder. As far as I can tell, the bitness of the caller (x64) agrees with the unfindable NuGet package (AnyCPU).

Even when I recompile everything to AnyCPU, the error message remains:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'ChoETL.Core, Version=1.2.1.28, etc.' The system cannot find the file specified.
```

My published NET 5 exe (x64) file calls a published NET 5 library that calls the Nuget package `ChoETL.Core` in the error message (exe->lib->ChoETL.Core).

Here is the command line that I used to build the program exe and intermediate library .csproj files. I do not use Visual Studio and do not use the solution .sln file. All files build without errors or warnings.

```
msbuild -t:restore;publish /p:Platform=x64 /p:PlatformTarget=x64 /p:Configuration=Debug /p:TargetFramework=net5.0-windows7.0 /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64  /p:PublishDir=c:\dev\holding\core.plt xxx.csproj
```

Here is the reference in the .csproj file of the library that references the `ChoETL.Core` package. Keep in mind that the msbuild command line properties override the `AnyCPU` values in the csproj file below.

```
   <PropertyGroup>
      <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
      <Platforms>AnyCPU</Platforms>
      <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
      <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows7.0</TargetFramework>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="ChoETL" Version="1.2.1.28" />
   </ItemGroup>
```

I thought maybe the CorFlags values might be the issue, so I checked them. There were as follows (32bitreq/prefs were zero):

```
Program.exe: PE32+, flags 0x9, ILONLY 1, Signed 1
Library.dll: PE32+, flags 0x9, ILONLY 1, Signed 1
ChoETL.Core: PE32, flags 0x1, ILONLY 1, Signed 0
```

PE32+ means x64, and PE32 means AnyCPU (if the assembly is loaded into a 64 process, it runs as a 64-bit assembly). So, they should be compatible (and besides, I cannot compile the NuGet package).

I looked at this SO question, but it did not help.
[Could not load file or assembly, system could not find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104018/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-could-not-find-the-file-specified)

Does anyone have any idea why the library cannot find the `ChoETL.Core.dll` library when all three assemblies are side by side in the same folder?
I've spent days on the problem without progress or success. Thank you.

Comment: Does that assembly have any other dependencies that can't be found?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. That's an interesting question. ChoETL (the NuGet package) depends on 10 or 20 other packages, but as far as I know, the NET 5 SDK project takes care of all of them. Also, I just built a small test project running that only needs the single assembly in the folder that contains the executable. So I don't think a chained dependency is the issue. It's a mystery to me at this point.

Answer (score 0):

After yet another day of debugging, I have things working, but I don't know exactly why. I started with a simple console program, then exe + lib, then exe + lib (that called ChoETL), and finally made a test case with part of my real system. By the time I got to experiments with part of the real system, things were working okay. But fragile, I imagine.

Here are some theories that might help the next person.

One key issue (in the real system that was failing) was that the ChoETL package was not being published by the `msbuild ... -t:clean;restore;publish` operation. I think this was a major part of the problem. Yet, as I built up my test experiments using the same msbuild command lines, ChoETL was always being published correctly beside the executables and libraries that consumed the package.

At that time, I recognized that my experiments always completely deleted the bin and obj folders before starting a new build, whereas my real system build files did not take that drastic action (thinking that msbuild clean/restore would be sufficient for a clean build). But, not so. Msbuild is not that smart. I modified my real-system build files to completely delete all obj/bin folders in the 70-project build sequence at the start of the build, and ChoETL was correctly published beside the assemblies that consumed it.

And at last, the original problem was solved (but not really understood). The system could find ChoETL and load it. All I know is that completely deleting the obj and bin folders at the start enabled a successful build. I do not have a clear idea of what file(s) or data elements in the obj/bin folders might have prevented a successful publish operation. Maybe it was the `project.assets.json` file, or maybe it was one of the other json files.

I do know that msbuild does not easily regenerate the json files when csproj files and msbuild command line properties are changed. I have developed the habit of completely deleting the obj/bin folders in the months since starting to work with NET 5 because of such problems.

I thought msbuild would do dependency and timestamp analysis like make does, and regenerate the json files if they were "out of date" (whatever that might mean in this context; I don't know). But it does not. Thus I have started to develop the habit of completely deleting the obj/bin folders before a build. Obviously, this experience (a development delay of weeks) shows that I still have much further to go with developing that into a rigid habit. I hope this answer might help someone else.

Comment: These days I think the ```project.assets.json``` file is the culprit. The VStudio 'clean;rebuild' sequence does not generate the same JSON file as msbuild does (when the json file is missing for msbuild). If the json file exists (even if incorrect), msbuild will not overwrite it with a correct json file. Deleting the obj/bin folders before an msbuild run deletes the file so that msbuild regenerates the correct one for msbuild. I'm going to guess that adding a PlatformTarget of win-x64 to the csproj file might enable VStudio to generate a correct file, but I have not tested that idea.